# ExpressionEngine conditional logic with related_entries

Tags: expressionengine

```
{if taxonomy != "" OR related_pages != "" OR related_posts != "" OR related_news != ""}
    <footer role="contentinfo">
        {if taxonomy != ""}
            <div id="taxonomy" itemprop="taxonomy">
                <h3>Category tags for this page</h3>

                <ul property="dcterms:type">
                    {exp:tagger:tags entry_id="{entry_id}" orderby=”tag_name”}
                        <li>
                            <a href="/page/tag/{tagger:urlsafe_tagname}" rel="tag">{tagger:tag_name}</a>
                        </li>
                    {/exp:tagger:tags}
                </ul>
            </div>
        {/if}

        {if related_pages != ""}
            <div id="related-pages">
                {related_entries id="related_pages"}
                    <h3>{title}</h3>
                    {body}
                {/related_entries}
            </div>
        {/if}

        {if related_posts != ""}
            <div id="related-posts">
                {related_entries id="related_posts"}
                    <h3>{title}</h3>
                    {body}
                {/related_entries}
            </div>
        {/if}

        {if related_news != ""}
            <div id="related-news">
                {related_entries id="related_news"}
                    <h3>{title}</h3>
                    {body}
                {/related_entries}
            </div>
        {/if}
    </footer>
{/if}
```

So, I am looking to write conditional code which firstly will only show a footer element if any of taxonomy, related_pages, related_posts or related_news are not empty. Note that related_* are all relationship field IDs.

Within this if statement are nested conditional statements which will only show content blocks if the corresponding IDs are not empty. Unfortunately, it seems that EE doesn't see relationship fields as ever being empty, even when no related content has been selected.

Does anyone know of either what is parsed by the relationship field IDs when no content has been selected, or another workaround to handle what I am trying to do in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit long winded, but...

```
{if "{taxonomy}" != "" OR 
    "{related_entries id="related_pages"}{entry_id}{/related_entries}" != "" OR
    "{related_entries id="related_posts"}{entry_id}{/related_entries}" != "" OR
    "{related_entries id="related_news"}{entry_id}{/related_entries}" != ""}
...
{if "{related_entries id="related_pages"}{entry_id}{/related_entries}" != ""}
...
{if "{related_entries id="related_posts"}{entry_id}{/related_entries}" != ""}
...
{if "{related_entries id="related_news"}{entry_id}{/related_entries}" != ""}
...
```

If your budget can stretch to it the [Playa](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/playa) add-on is the King of relationships and makes working with relationships a breeze.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am accessing SE on mobile at the moment, but will try out the code later today. Will Playa make this code easier to manage or is it just an aside that I should check it out?

Comment: Peter, you were very close with this but the code above does throw some exceptions. I will post another answer with the corrections I had to make. Thank you for putting me on the correct line.

Comment: Have amended for future reference as per your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to Peter Lewis for putting me on the right lines with this. Note that when you use double quotes around IDs, it appears you have to add them around each reference or else an exception is thrown. Also, the [limit attribute or count isn't available on related_entries](http://expressionengine.com/archived_forums/viewthread/90553/) but can be handled with a custom PHP count, as shown in the linked forum thread.

Here is the adapted template code that works:

```
{if "{taxonomy}" != "" OR 
    "{related_entries id="related_pages"}{entry_id}{/related_entries}" != "" OR
    "{related_entries id="related_posts"}{entry_id}{/related_entries}" != "" OR
    "{related_entries id="related_news"}{entry_id}{/related_entries}" != ""}
...
{if taxonomy != ""}
...
{if "{related_entries id="related_pages"}{entry_id}{/related_entries}" != ""}
...
{if "{related_entries id="related_posts"}{entry_id}{/related_entries}" !=   ""}
...
{if "{related_entries id="related_news"}{entry_id}{/related_entries}" != ""}
...
```

Comment: No worries. Annoying that reverse_related_entries supports the limit tag, but related_entries doesn't! Ref: http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/relationships.html#related-entries-tag-pair